# Regular expression with [a-zA-Z]{0,2}

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to a build a regular expression but it is not giving me the correct value

`Bookss` should match with the following :

```
Books
Bookss
Booksss
```

i.e the string can match with one character less or more or equal

I tried building the regular expression for the above case but it does not match

The regular expression i tried is:

```
String str="Books"

Pattern p=Pattern.compile(str.substring(0,input.length()-1)+"[a-zA-Z]{0,2}"

Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);

if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println("Found");
}
```

Comment: It looks like you just need to append `*` to the `str`. But it is a good idea to `Pattern.quote` it: `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(str) + "*")`. However, you wrote `Bookss` in the question, and you have `Books` in the code. What are the real input and rules? BTW, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/dQHQQk).

Comment: The `*` makes the preceding atom optional, makes it match 0 or more times. I think it is what you are looking for, right?

Comment: For ex : The input is 
Boo?s, for this output can be any one of the following 
1. Book/Booa
2. Books/Booka
3. Bookss/Bookaa,  So I build a regular expression Book.[a-z]{0,2}

Comment: The edges of the resultset are somewhat unclear to me. Which words should, for example, match the input string `Booksq`?

Comment: 1. Books/Booka ( one character less than the "Booksq") 2. Booksq/Booksa(equal length) 3. Booksqq/Booksqa( One character more than the input string)

Comment: why should `Booka` match `Booksq` ? it is not only one character less!

Comment: Can match with one character more , one character more, or equal

Comment: @Neha please write down exactly what you are trying to do (the rules of matching)

Comment: how is `Booka` "one character more or equal" *or less*  than `Booksq` ? My question again, why should `Booka` match `Booksq` - it is one character less and **one character replaced**!

Comment: Input is a string which Ex : Input, First Condition : The output can be any string which is one character less, one character more  or equal in length. So it can be Inpu, Input, Inputt. Second Condition : It says that when one character is more(it can be any character), when equal length( The last character in the string can be any character)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a regex such as

```
/Book.?.?.?\b/
```

such as:

```
String str="Books"

Pattern p=Pattern.compile(str.substring(0,input.length()-1)+".?.?.?\b";

Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);

if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println("Found");
}
```

The expression

```
.?
```

matches zero or one instances of any character, whereas

```
\b
```

limits it to the boundry of a word. (if the string input is to have muliple spaces in it, leave this off)

so,

```
.?.?.?\b
```

will match any three characters at the end of the word they are appended to.

Edit: missed the requirement of handling one character less or more.

Comment: I think he wanted it for any word they entered.

Comment: it will work for any word... given the code above... I just stayed with his 'Books' example. He could easily change str to whatever he would like.

Answer (score 0):

Try following one..

**Sample Code**

```
 String str="Booksss";

    Pattern p=Pattern.compile(str.substring(0,str.length()-1)+".?{0,2}");
    System.out.println(p);

    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);

if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println("Found");
}
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Thanks anyways everybody for answering

```
String input="Book.s";

Pattern p=Pattern.compile(input.substring(0,input.length()-1)+"[a-zA-Z]{0,2}$");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("Books");
if (matcher.find())
{
   System.out.println("Matches Regular Expression");
}
```

Comment: but this also matches `Boo` like in `...p.matcher("Boo");`

Comment: Please check, It should not match "Boo"